# Modifying arguments in remote EJB method

Tags: java, ejb

There are a lot of articles describing how modifications to EJB method arguments are not passed to the caller. I usually resolve this by returning the argument to the caller so it can be reassigned to a variable.

My problem is that none of the articles seem to describe what I should do in more complex methods where I need to make modifications to arguments and return some value. I could make some sort of wrapper class that contains property for each argument and the actual return value and return the wrapper, but that seems very clumsy to me. Are there better ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no other ways.

Imagine the following method:

```
Result doSomething(A arg1, B arg2, C arg3) { 
  ...
}
```

Because you are calling your EJB using remote connection, the client will serialize `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg3`. At this point, they are completely new instance, say `arg1'`, `arg2'` and `arg3'`.

They are probably not even on the same JVM, and if it were, you should not rely on that (some EJB container use reference when they determine that caller and called are in the same JVM).

Returning a `Result`, taking those `argN'` updated is the only way:

```
Result doSomething(A arg1, B arg2, C arg3) {
  ...      
  return new Result(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}
```

Then the container will serialize `Result`, and `arg1'`, `arg2'` and `arg3'`, and the caller will receive `Result'` containing `arg1"`, `arg2"` and `arg3"`.

Comment: I guess I have to live with that. I was hoping that there is some annotation for argument that would say "send this argument back and replace the instance in the caller side".

Comment: I'd think that as long as you leave the JVM, this is near impossible - or it is too much problems for too small benefits.